# How to avoid corruption of url?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using following method to call function of controller from script with arguments

```
  $("#export-it-Voip").attr("href", '@Url.Action("ExportAllToExcel", "Home")?strvoicerecordfetchquery=' + voipquery + '&nSelectAllten=' + 10+'&nbSelectAll='+1);
```

but my voipquery contain string like

```
"SELECT * FROM  T100TRAFFIC  WHERE NTYPE = 7 AND UPPER(VCDESCRIPTION) LIKE UPPER('%cal%')  ORDER BY DTTIME DESC "
```

but at controller it is coming as

```
SELECT * FROM  T100TRAFFIC  WHERE NTYPE = 7 AND UPPER(VCDESCRIPTION) LIKE UPPER('�l%')  ORDER BY DTTIME DESC
```

that means some of the chars are getting changed. How to avoid it?

Answer (score 2):

Before you do *anything* else: **Stop exposing yourself to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).** I don't know what your use case is, but allowing an SQL command as a query string parameter like that is almost certainly a *terrible* idea.

I don't know what tools you're using to access the database, but start by reshaping your SQL string into this:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM
    T100TRAFFIC
WHERE
    NTYPE = 7
AND
    UPPER(VCDESCRIPTION) LIKE '%'+UPPER(@search)+'%'
ORDER BY
    DTTIME DESC
```

This has a parameter `@search`, which you can fill with the search string.

On your action method, you now take only the search string - not the entire SQL command, as a parameter:

```
public ActionResult ExportAllToExcel(string query, int selectAllTen, int selectAll)
```

and on the client,

```
$("#export-it-Voip").attr("href", '@Url.Action("ExportAllToExcel", "Home")?query=' + voipquery + '&nSelectAllten=' + 10+'&nbSelectAll='+1);
```

where `voipquery` is now a JavaScript variable with the query string, e.g. `var voipquery = 'cal'`.

---

Edit: I just got a number of downvotes on this answer, so I figured I'd improve it with some rationale for the above suggestions.

To start with, SQL injection is one of the most common attack vectors for malicious users (read: hackers). It is also one of the most dangerous ones in terms of what a successful attacker can accomplish; if you're unlucky, you'll expose your entire database for both reading and modification. Thus, worrying about that before worrying about other things is a good idea.

Secondly, it just so happens that the suggested solution actually helps with the original problem too. Given the OP's description, it's likely that the problem is encoding-related, and parametrizing the query can take away at least some of the issues there. And if it doesn't, you're in a better place to start looking for other encoding problems.